# How to update an array at a particular index with React js

Tags: reactjs

I have a state array in my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {myarray: []};
}
```

Now I want to update the array at a specific subscript.

```
this.setState({myarray[i]: 'test'});
```

gives me an `unexpected token` error, pointing at the opening bracket `[`

What is the correct way of doing that?

P.S. Array gets filled dynamically using `push` method and only then I attempt to update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a copy of the array:

```
const newArray = Array.from(this.state.myarray);
```

update the index:

```
newArray[i] = 'test';
```

and update the state

```
this.setState({myarray: newArray});
```

---

You can also use [immutable helpers](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) ([used to be part of React's addons](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)) to do this more concisely.