# In React, what is the right way to update nested array state items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When using React (without Redux). Assuming I have component state that looks like this:

```
{
    rows: [
    {
      items:[
         {
           value:'a',
           errors: false
         },
         {
           value:'b',
           errors: false
         },
         {
           value:'c',
           errors: false
         }
     ]
  }
```

Also assuming that the rows and items can be of length 0 > n.

What is the best (most efficient, common, agreed, popular etc) way to update the value of any of the items, i.e.

```
this.state.rows[0].item[1]
```

I realise that I can do:

```
let updatedRows = this.state.rows
updatedRows[0].item[1].value = 'new value'

this.setState({
  rows: updatedRows
})
```

Is this generally accepted what of doing this? Isn't it inefficient to replace pretty much the whole state object to change a single value?

Comment: If you rephrase the question as to `How would I do this in JavaScript without React?` you'd have your answer. If you however ask `Where would I do this?` then you'd have a different question.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [How to update an array at a particular index with React js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42147193/218196)

Comment: @HenrikAndersson - I think the relevance of React is important because of what happens with state? I know how to do it with Javascript - what I'm interested in is the effect it has etc. I'll update my Question if you think it necessary ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let updatedRows = this.state.rows
updatedRows[0].item[1].value = 'new value'
```

Because `item[1]` is an object, changing its `value` mutates your state since it refers to the same object.

You should never mutate the state directly because when you modify the state directly, react won't fire the relevant lifecycle events. From the docs (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

I like to use the [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) library to make copies of objects in the state. For example to change the `value` of `this.state.rows[0].item[1]` to `z`:

```
this.setState({rows: update(this.state.rows, 
        { 0: { item: { 1: { value: { $set: 'z' } } } } }
    )});
```

Comment: Thanks for this @FuzzyTree - Any chance you could give me an example of the command for updating row items when the row index and item index are dynamic (stored in rowIndex and index variables, for instance)?

Comment: No worries ... I got it:

this.setState({rows: update(this.state.rows, 
        { [rowIndex]: { item: { [index]: { value: { $set: 'z' } } } } }
    )});

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure which one is most popular or best, these things changes everyday. I use [lodash.set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set) for assigning

```
function updateItem(rowIndex, itemIndex, value) {
   const tmp = this.state.rows;
   _.set(tmp, `[${rowIndex}].item[${itemIndex}]`, value);
  this.setState({rows: tmp});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `immutability-helper` too.

for example:

```
this.state = {
    coupons: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'coupon1'
        },
        {   
            id: 2,
            title: 'coupon2'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'coupon3'
        }
    ]
}
```

And, you want to add a extend field like `isChecked` when user click the `coupon`.

```
handleCouponClick = (coupon, idx) => {
    const newState = {
        coupons: update(this.state.coupons, {
            [idx]: {
                isChecked: {$set: !this.state.coupons[idx].isChecked}
            }
        })
    };

    this.setState(newState);
}
```

So, the component will `re-render` and you can use the `isChecked` field to do something.