# how to update 2d array using indices in setState?

Tags: reactjs

```
state={
array:[]
}

onChange=(i,j,a)=>{
   this.setState({ array[i][j]: a}) // i want to perform this task
}
```

how do I use mutation and updation together?
i don't want to use mutation libraries

edit: Also for arr[ [1,2], [3,4] ,[5,6] ]
for 4 i=j=1

Comment: Make a *deep* copy of the array (spread operator doesn't do deep clone), change the value in the cloned array, then set the state value to that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
onChange=(i,j,a)=>{
    let newArray = Array.from(this.state.array);
    newArray[i][j] = a;
    this.setState({array: newArray});
}
```

I am writing this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147193/how-to-update-an-array-at-a-particular-index-with-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the state array and set the value then reset.

```
changedHandler = (i,j,a) => {
 let clonedArray = [...this.state.array];
 if(clonedArray[i][j]){
      clonedArray[i][j]= a;
      this.setState({array: clonedArray});
 }
}
....
onChange={(i,j,a)=> changedHandler(i,j,a)}
```

Comment: what if array is a list of list. arr[ [], [], [] ] .how will i do this in that?

Comment: you can again create copy of level of array which is needed and mutate safely. May be like this let clonedSubArray =  [...clonedArray[i][j]]; 
clonedSubArray = value; //Value to be changed
clonedArray[i][j] = clonedSubArray;
this.setState({array: clonedArray})

Comment: If the levels are not known and you want to deep copy your state array you can use like this: let arrayCopy = []; **Object.assign(arrayCopy, array)**. Then modify the required value in arrayCopy and set the array state with arrayCopy.

Comment: i'm getting error "cannot set property 0 of undefined" . the array is actually initially empty. (is it because of that). then how to push first .can you share the code?

Comment: yes, may be. Before cloning check if array is defined and also before setting value of array of array.